# How to validate IEnumerable of a class within another IEnumerable of a class using fluent validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, fluentvalidation

I have these classes

```
public class CryptocurrencyDto
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Cryptocurrency> Cryptocurrencies { get; set; }
}

public class Cryptocurrency : BaseClass
{
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double TotalSupply { get; set; }
    public double CirculatingSupply { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Note
{
    public int NoteId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Url> Urls { get; set; }
    public byte Image { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
}

public class Url
{
    public string UrlId { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have this endpoint

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] CryptocurrencyDto cryptocurrency)
    {

    }
```

How do I validate through these classes? So far I only know how to validate the first class `CryptocurrencyDto`. I don't know how to reach the other classes. Cryptocurrency, Note and Url.

Comment: Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

As you added FluentValidation to your question tags, this is the `Collection Validation` using FluentValidation:

```
public class CryptocurrencyDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<CryptocurrencyDto> {
  public CryptocurrencyDtoValidator() {
    RuleForEach(x => x.Cryptocurrency).NotNull();
  }
}
```

[More info](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/index.html)

But there are many other ways to use validation for associated classes (e.g. `T` or `IEnumerable<T>`):

1. Create and use `ValidationAttribute`: [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#validation-attributes)
2. Implement `IValidatableObject`: [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ivalidatableobject)
3. Check any associated classes in the `Controller` Level.